# How to search in 2D array by LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have an **2D array** like this:

```
string[,] arr=
{
    {"1","ali"},
    {"2","mehdi"},
    {"3","john"},
    {"4","milad"},
};
```

i search **name** in **2nd** column by **for** statement like this:

```
string name="";
for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
     if (arr[i, 1].StartsWith("m"))
     {
         name = arr[i, 1];
         break;
     }
}
Response.Write(name);
```

i want use **LINQ** instead of **for** statement to get the first **name** that start with 'm'.
how to convert above **for** statement to **LINQ**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var name = arr.Cast<string>()
              .Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 1 && x.StartsWith("m"))
              .First();
```

`i % 2 == 1` will take only items from second column and `x.StartWith("m")` will take only names that start with `'m'`.

And you have to use `Cast<string>()` before other LINQ methods, because multidimensional arrays does not implement generic `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @SamieyMehdi - Have you tried using this? you havent changed the type of array so don't see why it would change the answer

Comment: @SamieyMehdi Sorry, but we're not play cat and mouse. That's the third version of the question. I've already answered two previous and I'm done. You should have ask *the right* question at the beginning or create another one after the first was answered.

Comment: I know it does not work now. It doesn't because you changed the question. That's the answer for your initial one, which is available in [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18672560/1). And I'm not going to delete it, because it's correct regarding the question it was written for.